# struggling with fputc in c

Tags: c, file

In the file `"file1.dat"` I wrote `"anahasapples"`.
 And then I wrote this program:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE *ptr_file;
        ptr_file=fopen("file1.dat","r+");
        printf("%c",fgetc(ptr_file));
        printf("%c",fgetc(ptr_file));
        printf("%c\n",fgetc(ptr_file));
        char c;
        printf("char:\n");
        c=getch();
        fputc(c,ptr_file);

        return 0;
    }
```

The part where I print the first 3 characters from the file works. After that, I want to put a char into the file.
 When I compile this, I don't get any errors, but the containing text doesn't change.

Comment: You need to `fclose` your file before the program returns.

Comment: @mathematician1975: `need to` is not true, as the file is closed implictly when the program ends. However it is good style to explcitly close the file.

Comment: @alk Yes **need** was a poor choice of word. I meant it as you have described rather than as a necessity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Documentation for fopen()](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?fopen) standardly shows the following explanation:

> When a file is opened with update mode (+ as the  second  or third
>   character in the mode argument), both input and output may be
>   performed on the associated stream.  However,  output must  not be
>   directly followed by input without an intervening call to fflush(3C)
>   or to a file positioning  function  (fseek(3C), fsetpos(3C) or
>   rewind(3C)), and input must not be directly followed by output without
>   an intervening call to a file   positioning  function,  unless  the 
>   input  operation encounters end-of-file.

Just add an fseek() to your code and all works well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    ptr_file=fopen("file1.dat","r+");
    printf("%c",fgetc(ptr_file));
    printf("%c",fgetc(ptr_file));
    printf("%c\n",fgetc(ptr_file));
    char c;
    printf("char:\n");
    c=getch();
    fseek( ptr_file, 0, SEEK_CUR );   /* Add this line */
    int err = fputc(c,ptr_file);
    printf ("err=%d\n", err);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my file1.dat before and after inputting an 'x':

Before

> anahasapples

After

> anaxasapples

It seems that by default the fputc() tries to write past the end of the file, so you need to reposition the file pointer (e.g., using fseek) to make the write occur at the point of the current file pointer.

Comment: hey Rubin. Thank you very much. Could you please explain me what the '0' parameter means?

Comment: My bible for C functions is die.net, for `fseek` look at http://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek which explains that the `0` is for an additional offset which would be added to `SEEK_CUR`. Since you don't want to add any extra *offset* then it is `0`.

Comment: Let me point you to the fseek() documentation (for example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) for a full explanation.  Briefly, the second and third arguments work together: the file pointer is set to the origin plus the offset.  For example, (10, SEEK_SET) means "ten bytes from the beginning of the file", (12, SEEK_END) means "12 bytes from the end of the file", and (0, SEEK_CUR) means "set the file pointer to the current file pointer (with no offset)".

Answer (score 1):

set the pointer first

```
 fseek(ptr_file, ftell (ptr_file), SEEK_SET);
        fputc(c,ptr_file);
```

See this link for explanation http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/files_8.htm

http://www.rainydayz.org/beej/bgc/fseek.html